# How to track number of matches in Karate framework?

Tags: karate

I have a karate test and I am trying to figure out how to track the number of matches?
So.. We have thise response:

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLbfq.png)

And this assertion:

And match response.results[*].tenantId contains 10

**How can I check/count the number of correct assertions in this case**? Basically in the example above, it should be 3. (3 out of 4 tenantId are equal to 10)

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: to OP: I agree with above comment, please edit your question to include the example, and you will get an answer soon

Answer (score 1):

You can use the json to get the items you need then match the count to whatever you need it to match to:

```
* def tenantIdsMatch = karate.jsonPath(response, ".results[?(@.tenantId == 10)]")

And match tenantIdsMatch == '#[_ > 0]'
```

https://karatelabs.github.io/karate/#jsonpath-filters